# rails query generates oci:error quoted string incorrectly terminated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-2, oracle-call-interface

I have the following code(very legacy) in the application:

```
  results << User.all(
  :select => "'#{entry.name}' AS user_name, '#{entry.lastname}, #{entry.firstname}' AS user_full_name, display_name", 
  :order => "display_name")
```

Which generates the following query I get the following oci error:

```
  OCIError: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated: 
SELECT 'theupsstore2579' AS user_name, 'O'Brien, Perry' AS user_full_name, display_name FROM "Users" WHERE..
```

Is there a good way to fix my query?

Is using quote_string a good way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a good way. You should not ever use interpolated strings eg `"string bit #{interpolated_bit}"` in a sql query - this is very bad for security and leads to SQL injection attacks.

In this case - because one of the names includes a `'` character (in the last-name `O'Brien` - and once that value is inserted into your SQL string, it treats it like it would any `'` character and ends the string - even though there is more after the `'` (namely the `Brien` bit)

That then causes a syntax error for your database.

However - using the interpolated strings this way also leaves you open to SQL injection - what if somebody typed in `'; DROP TABLE users;` (or equivalent) into their last name field? and your code happily put that into the SQL and ran it? Your way of using interpolated strings is *NOT* safe. But Rails provides alternatives that *are* safe - and they are what you should always use.

eg the built-in arel methods (`where` `select` `order` etc) and use the sanitised `?` syntax so instead of

```
results << User.all(
  :select => "'#{entry.name}' AS user_name, '#{entry.lastname}, #{entry.firstname}' AS user_full_name, display_name", 
  :order => "display_name")
```

you could try

```
results << User.select("'?' AS user_name, '?, ?' AS user_full_name, display_name", entry.name, entry.lastname, entry.firstname).order("display_name")
```

(though I question why you want to force all users to have the same name - did you actually want these to be conditions selecting only users with those names instead?)

I strongly recommend you read through all of the Rails Guides. In this case especially the one on how to use [Active Record queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html):

and also you might want to read up the security guide - specifically, in this case, the  [Rails guide SQL injection section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)

Comment: This is rails 2, can I add :conditions to the above query?

Comment: @newbie is there a reasons why you *need* to be on Rails 2? it's now many years out of date and no longer supported. I'd strongly recommend upgrading.

Comment: it's an old legacy application we dont have the resources/time to upgrade/rewrite it yet.

Comment: I didnt copy the conditions part in the above code:  :conditions => ["id IN (?)", array]. I will look into this

Comment: Ah right - my commiserations. Sure - yes you can convert to conditions... I vaguely recall a way to pass selects to old-style rails too.